# Regular expression for exact match or similar of a word

Tags: c#, regex

i need to find similar or exact words in the text line. e.g:

i have the following pattern:
`(Abarth|Alfa\s+Romeo|Aston\s+Martin|Audi|Austin)`

and input string is: `Alfa Rom` or `Alfa Romeo Contata`
as result should be: `Alfa Romeo` as possible.

i have a got over 100 makes and i would like to use them in "auto complete".

how can do such search with regex pattern?

Comment: Make the optional part optional using `?`

Comment: @NaveedS sorry not understand your question. i wanna use it for "auto complete".

Comment: that was not a question. what i told you was to make the optional part in the string optional by appending a question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark makes the preceding token in the regular expression optional. E.g.: `colou?r` matches both `colour` and `color`.

You can make several tokens optional by grouping them together using round brackets, and placing the question mark after the closing bracket. E.g.: `Nov(ember)?` will match `Nov` and `November`.

You can write a regular expression that matches many alternatives by including more than one question mark. `Feb(ruary)? 23(rd)?` matches `February 23rd`, `February 23`, `Feb 23rd` and `Feb 23`.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i wanna use it for "auto complete", and i cannot populate all possible combinations

Comment: @Miro post your auto complete code and text which u use for auto completion.